# NetworkImageView to occupy full width of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley

I am using com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.
Image is coming from url.
I want to display image so that its width to occupy full width of screen not height because below image there is a caption which is a Textview.

Here is the activity's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the items xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button_register" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/photo_image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Check"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From the backend the image size is 300 X 200 pixels.
How to set imageview so that it can occupy full width of the screen.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NetworkImageView` extends `ImageView` so you should be able to use everything that works with `ImageView`.

So, if you want your image to occupy full width and adjust its height so it maintains its aspect ratio (at least that's what I understood you wanted to do) use the [`adjustViewBounds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) property

Your xml will look like this:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/button_register"
    <!-- add adjustViewBounds -->
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```